# Can we use instances of Object class as keys in HashMap

Tags: java

The question is simple as title:

> Can we use instances of Object class as keys in HashMap?

I am not talking about using any custom class as key, but using `Object` class instances as a key.
Do we need to take any precautions if at all we can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to use instances of Object as a map's key:

```
Map<Object, SomeOtherType> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But this may be a dangerous thing to do, as this means that objects of *any* type can be used as a key object, including objects that are not immutable, and if a key object is used that is an object whose `.equals(...)` or `.hashCode()` can later change, expect some bad side-effects with maps that break. This is true for *any* map where the key is potentially mutable.

Per the [Map API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

So in sum: yes, this is possible, but don't do it